# Ist es korrekt, die Gegenwart für vergangene Sachverhalte zu verwenden, um vorige Folge von Ereignissen anzuzeigen?

Tags: verb-choice

Beispiel:

> Schließlich schreibt er sich in Zürich am Polytechnikum ein und vertieft sich in die Physik. Nur wenige Jahre später, 1905, schickt er drei Artikel an die damals renommierteste wissenschaftliche Zeitschrift, die «Annalen der Physik». Alle drei sind nobelpreiswürdig.

Ist das üblich genug, dass ich mich daran gewöhnen sollte? Hat es einen literarischen Namen? In englischer Sprache würde Präsens nur in einer Geschichte und nicht in einer historischen Überblick sinnvoll sein.

Comment: "Zeitzeugenbericht"

Comment: I'm afraid this question is not very specific to the German language - This literary form shows up in nearly any language.

Comment: @tofro There are very few things in tense systems that show up in nearly every language – [one might even say none at all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_tense).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ja, daran solltest du dich gewöhnen. Diese Art, das Präsens zu verwenden heißt [historisches Präsens](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historisches_Pr%C3%A4sens). Es ist ein Stilmittel, das genau in solchen Fällen wie in deinem Beispiel gerne verwendet wird.

Der Kontext (z.B. Jahreszahlen) macht dem Leser eindeutig klar, dass hier ein Ereignis aus der Vergangenheit beschrieben wird. Das Präsens wird gewählt, um die Schilderung emotional näher an den Leser heranzuführen.

Es handelt sich übrigens dabei nicht, wie in einem Kommentar erwähnt, um einen Zeitzeugenbericht. Ein Zeitzeuge ist jemand, der bei dem Ereignis selbst dabei war. Um das Präsens verwenden zu dürfen, müsste der Zeitzeuge das Ereignis aufschreiben während es gerade geschieht. Das ist selten. Auch Zeitzeugen schreiben ihre Erlebnisse meist erst später auf (Stunden oder Tage danach), was das Präteritum erforderlich machen würde.

Das historische Präsens kann man aber auch für Ereignisse verwenden, bei denen ganz sicher kein Zeitzeuge dabei war:

> Aus dem Urknall entsteht zunächst ein völlig opakes Universum. Erst nach etwas weniger als 400.000 Jahren beginnt es durchsichtig zu werden.

---

Der Behauptung des Fragestellers widersprechend gibt es das historische Präsens auch in Englisch, es heißt dort [historical present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present) und wird auch genau so verwendet, wie hier beschrieben. Viele andere Sprachen kennen dieses Stilmittel ebenfalls.

Comment: "Es handelt sich übrigens dabei nicht, wie in einem Kommentar erwähnt, um einen Zeitzeugenbericht." - das hängt vermutlich davon ab, ob man sich den Erzähler als tatsächlichen Beobachter vorstellt, welcher die Ereignisse vor Ort beschreibt. Ein fiktiver Zeitzeuge sozusagen, als Kontrast zu einem späteren Schreiber, der dann genau nicht Präsens wählen würde. Ob dieser fiktive Zeitzeuge seine Beobachtungen später zu Papier bringt, ist an der Stelle unerheblich, da man ebensogut direkt die "Gedanken" des Zeitzeugen vom Augenblick der Beobachtung hören/lesen könnte.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Nein. Ein Zeuge, auch wenn er fiktiv ist, gibt seine eigenen Beobachtungen wieder. So einen Zeugen müsste man sich als Person vorstellen, die anwesend ist, während sich der Held der Handlung in etwas vertieft, und sie müsste diese Vertiefung auch als Vorgang beobachten. Auch müsste dieser Zeuge zwei Vorgänge, die im Abstand von zwei Jahren geschehen, so wahrnehmen, als geschähen sie innerhalb weniger Sekunden. Anders wäre es nicht möglich, in zwei direkt aufeinanderfolgenden Sätzen in der Gegenwart vom Einschreiben am Polytechnikum und von Abschicken dreier Artikel zu reden. ...

Comment: ... Diese Deutung hält einer genaueren Betrachtung nicht stand. Wesentlich sinnvoller ist es, das Ganze als das zu betrachten, was es in Wirklichkeit ist: Eine sehr viel später verfasste Schilderung von recherchierten Tatsachen, die belegbare Ereignisse in der Vergangenheit wiedergibt. Dem Präsens, als Ausdruck des Unmittelbaren, wohnt nämlich gegenüber allen anderen Zeitformen der stärkste Ausdruck des Wahrhaftigen inne, weshalb es sich weit besser eignet Fakten zum Ausdruck zu bringen als andere Tempora.

Comment: "So einen Zeugen müsste man sich als Person vorstellen, die anwesend ist" - ja, genau. Wenn ich es darauf anlege, mir vorzustellen, wessen Stimme ich (z.B. bei einem historischen Dokumentarfilm) höre, stelle ich mir normalerweise einen zeitreisenden unsichtbaren Menschen vor, der die wichtigsten Punkte in der Entwicklung der dokumentierten historischen Entität besucht und direkt von dort berichtet.